# Arrays.asList works

Tags: java, arrays

I have taken two arrays in my below code snippet,

```
String[] things = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};
int[] a1 ={1,2,3,4,5};
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(things).contains("c"));
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(a1).contains(3));
```

and my outputs are

true 
false

I know when we use Arrays.asList we get an wrapper object which points to the existing array for random access, but in true sense an object of list interface is not created.

My question here is when the contains method works for string, why does it not work for int.

Answer (score 7):

`Arrays.asList` for an int array (or similarly for any primitive array) produces a `List<int[]>` whose single element is that int array. That's why `contains(3)` returned false (`System.out.println(Arrays.asList(a1).contains(a1));` would return true).

If you call `Arrays.asList` for an `Integer` array, you'll get a `List<Integer>` an `contains` will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
int[] a1 ={1,2,3,4,5};
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(a1).contains(3));
```

you could use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).contains(3));
```

The signature of `asList()` is `asList(T... a)` ㄧ i.e. it takes a vararg, so there is no need for explicit array creation. The constructor will take care of autoboxing.